# Steadier wheels - Pin them or lock springs

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

When running on a hard surface, the Create will shake sometimes during turns or acceleration.

Has anyone ever removed the springs or pinned the wheels in place so they can't move up and down?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* kirkLennard, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, **what you tried, what you saw** & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: It looks like you solved your own problem, but in general [hypothetical questions](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) ("Would ___ solve my problem?") are not appropriate for this site. *Try* your guess, and if that works, you solved your problem. If it doesn't work, *then* come state your problem along with *what you tried and what you saw*.

Answer (score 1):

We did take the springs out. It appears to make it steadier ride on a hard surface when accelerating or turning.